# Cataract and UV protective myopia lens

Tags: uv-rays, myopia-nearsightedness

Will UV protective myopia lens lessen advancing the early cataract (i.e. not to make it worse)?

I found that [wearing good quality UV protective eyewear is of tremendous benefit](https://afamilyoptician.co.uk/uv-cataracts/) to prevent cataract. But, does it lessen the advancement of the early cataract?